# Laravel 5.4 - group by, count and join

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have two tables (models have the same name as the tables):

```
StatusNames: id|name
```

and

```
CurrentUserStatus: id|user_id|status_id
```

At the moment **CurrentUserStatus** is empty, and **StatusNames** have several records inserted (Active, Inactive, On Pause, Terminated...).

I need to get all data from **CurrentUserStatus** and show how much are there within each status (given the current tables, next to each status name there should be zero (0)).

Is this possible to do with one query?

Comment: Yes you can but let me be clear you want to group and count the numbers from `CurrentUserStatus` table by `status_id` column?

Comment: Yes, tables are connected via **status_id** (as $this->hasOne('App\StatusNames')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So whatever I assumed you can do something like this:

```
$dataset = CurrentUserStatus::whereHas('status')
        ->with('status')
        ->withCount('status')
        ->orderBy('status_count', 'dsc')
        ->get();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Helps a bit :). I am getting empty set at the moment, but I think I will do it :)

Comment: I'm glad it help.